# subprocess.call() failed with error -43 After Catalina update

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I had a piece of code to launch the messages app in a python script which worked for years, but it inexplicably started failing after the update to macOS Catalina 10.15

I was using the subprocess API to run a bash command

```
subprocess.call(
    ["/usr/bin/open", "-a", "/Applications/messages.app"])
```

Previously, this worked fine but now I get the error 
FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/messages.app) failed with error -43.

Comment: It's probably because there's no such app named `messages.app`. Please consider checking if such an app exists, or if you've simply spelled the name of the app wrong.

Comment: That's the correct name for the App

Comment: Are you sure about that? The only (system) app I know that has a name similar to that is `Messages.app`, located at `/Applications/Messages.app`.

Comment: File names in bash aren't case sensitive but here's the error anyway ```FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Messages.app) failed with error -43.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using os instead of subprocess.

```
import os
#...
os.system("open -a messages")
```

Though I'm still not really sure why it stoped working to begin with.

Comment: You are not just using ``os`` instead of ``subprocess``, you are running a different program -- ``messages`` instead of ``/Applications/messages.app``. Does ``subprocess.call(["open", "-a", "messages"])`` work?

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 0):

The message app is moved to /System/Applications/

```
$open "/System/Applications/Messages.app"
```

Catalina has moved some files to a dedicated volume but in Finder they remained at the same place, [as documented here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT210650)

> macOS Catalina runs on a dedicated, read-only system volume called Macintosh HD. This volume is completely separate from all other data to help prevent the accidental overwriting of critical operating system files. Your files and data are stored in another volume named Macintosh HD - Data. In the Finder, both volumes appear as Macintosh HD.